# Need to return seq<R> instead of seq<seq<R>>?

Tags: f#

The following function `files` returns `seq<seq<R>>`. How to make it return `seq<R>` instead?

```
type R = { .... }
let files = seqOfStrs |> Seq.choose(fun s ->
    match s with
    | Helper.ParseRegex "(\w+) xxxxx" month ->
        let currentMonth =  .....
        if currentMonth = month.[0] then
            doc.LoadHtml(s)
            Some (
                doc.DucumentNode.SelectNodes("....")
                |> Seq.map(fun tr ->
                    { ..... } ) //R. Some code return record type R. Omitted
            )
        else
            printfn "Expect %s found %s." currentMonth month.[0]
            None
    | _ ->
        printfn "No '(Month) Payment Data On Line' prompt."
        None
```

Comment: Seq.concat ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353462.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet is incomplete and so we can't give you a fully working answer. But:

- Your code is using `Seq.choose` and you are returning either `None` or `Some` with collection of values. Then you get a sequence of sequences...
- You can use `Seq.collect` which flattens the sequences and replace `None` with an empty sequence and `Some` with just the sequence.

Something along those lines (untested):

```
let files = seqOfStrs |> Seq.collect (fun s ->
    match s with
    | Helper.ParseRegex "(\w+) xxxxx" month ->
        let currentMonth =  .....
        if currentMonth = month.[0] then
            doc.LoadHtml(s)
            doc.DucumentNode.SelectNodes("....")
            |> Seq.map(fun tr ->
                { ..... } ) //R. Some code return record type R. Omitted
        else
            printfn "Expect %s found %s." currentMonth month.[0]
            Seq.empty
    | _ ->
        printfn "No '(Month) Payment Data On Line' prompt."
        Seq.empty )
```

The other options like adding `Seq.concat` or `Seq.collect id` to the end of the pipeline would obviously work too.

Comment: Perfect. I tried to convert `Seq.choose` to `Seq.collect` without removing the the `Some(  )` and change `None` to `Seq.emtpy` and got errors. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You want to pipe the whole thing to Seq.collect.

for example,

```
files |> Seq.collect id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an F# [sequence expresssion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) to flatten the `seq` of `seq`s into a `seq`. Say you have:

```
> let xss = seq { for i in 1 .. 2 -> seq { for j in 1 .. 2 -> i * j } };;

val xss : seq<seq<int>>

> xss;;                                                                  
val it : seq<seq<int>> = seq [seq [1; 2]; seq [2; 4]]
```

Then you can do:

```
> seq { for x in xss do yield! x };;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2; 2; 4]
```

Behind the scenes, the sequence expression is doing the same thing as `Seq.collect`, just in a more syntax-sugary way.